# GET request success in Ruby code but fails in Node.js

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, http, get

I wrote the following code using Ruby. the following line of code

```
puts WhatDepsService.new(packages, os)
```

calls instantiates WhatDepsService calss and sends the following query

```
{packages: ['example1', example2, 'example3'], os: 'linux', pack_type: 'gem'}
```

in an http GET request and recieves a response successfully with code 200

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class WhatDepsService
    include HTTParty

    base_uri 'http://localhost:3000'

    def initialize()
        @options = {query: {packages: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'], os: 'linux', pack_type: 'gem'}}
        @packages = load_deps(@options)
    end

    private

    def load_deps(options)
        begin
            deps = self.class.get("/package", options)
            JSON.parse(deps.to_json)
        rescue
            abort "Sorry, there's a problem connecting to our server"
        end
    end
end
```

Now I wrote this code using node.js which is supposed to send the same http GET request:

```
var request = require('request');

var getLibs = function() {
    var options = { packages: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'], os: 'linux', pack_type: 'npm' }

    request({url:'http://localhost:3000/package', qs:options}, function (error , response, body) {
        if (! error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else{
            console.log(response.statusCode);
        }
    });
}();
```

But the request in node.js receives a response code 422 (Unprocessable Entity). How can I fix this?

***UPDATE***

The API receives the request from Ruby as follows:

```
{"packages"=>["example1", "example2", "example3"], "os"=>"linux", "pack_type"=>"gem"}
```

But receives the request from Node.js as follows:

```
{"packages"=>{"0"=>"example1", "1"=>"example2", "2"=>"example3"}, "os"=>"linux", "pack_type"=>"npm"}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm the owner of both questions (I'm the one commenting on your answer too). This was my original question. However, I will delete one of them as soon as I find an answer that actually solves my problem :)